# Salesforce Bulk API query image (on cms) associated with all products (on b2b)

Tags: b2b-commerce, b2b, salesforce-cms

I'm using Bulk API and to download my Salesforce B2B data. However now i am stuck trying to get the image info associated with product. Because images are in the Salesforce CMS app, i am not able to find its relationship to the Product2 product in B2B. 
 
I tried download the following sObjects through Bulk API and the result is next to them 
```ProductMedia, ProductCategoryMedia, Image ``` - are empty 
```ElectronicMediaUse``` - has data about ElectronicMediaGroup and ImageId 
```ElectronicMediaGroup``` - has nothing but details of the groups 
```ManagedContent``` - cannot access through Bulk API (sObject type 'ManagedContent' is not  supported.) 
 
According to the docs, ProductMedia should contain the info about the product and its associated media.

Could someone please let me know why i can see that a product is mapped to the image when i login to my org but not from the sObjects?

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is old, but in case you (or someone else) is still facing this - ProductMedia is definitely the object that holds the association between Product2 and and the ManagedContentInfo record (ID of which is referred to as ElectronicMediaId and is what points to the CMS image).  Can you run a SOQL query on ProductMedia in Workbench and see if you get any results there?

Comment: Thanks, Victor. At the time of writing my question, this wasn't completely developed/supported by salesforce. I hope it is now.